# Control font size \part

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, parts

I used a former question on TeX.SE to find the command `\part*{}`.  I like everything about it but the font for it is huge.  How can I tone down the size of the font for this command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\part*{Min}
new
\section{a}
new2
\section{b}
new3

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\part` and `\part*` in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) is:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{% <------------------------------- \part[..]{...}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart% Part font
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2% Title font
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{% <------------------------------- \part*{...}
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \huge \bfseries #1\par}% Title font
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
```

You can include these in your document and modify the "font" parts (highlighted above; "Part font" and "Title font") to your liking. There's also packages like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) that can help. Using the latter, is as easy as

```
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/secsty
\partfont{\large\bfseries}
```

to change the "Part font" to `\large\bfseries`.

Expanding on the former (raw) LaTeX code, to change the font specifically for `\part*`, use something like

```
\def\@spart#1{% <------------------------------- \part*{...}
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \large \bfseries #1\par}% Title font
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
```

where I've changed the `\huge` font size to `\large`, keeping it **bold**.

Remember to wrap the macro redefinition with a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

Comment: Beautiful.  I went with `LARGE` instead but spot on with `sectsty` approach.  Thank you. +1