# Choice of font size in part name and numbering

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I would like to use bigger fonts (14pt) for the name and the numbering of the parts, except in the TOC. I know that I must use the package `titlesec` but I do not understand how. There is a similar question for a different class here : [Control font size \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79899/89734). The package `sectsty` does not work with amsart.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\Roman{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{thm}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}

\begin{document}
    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents


\part{blabla}

\section{blablabla}


\begin{thm}
    The integer $1+1$ is finite.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
    The integer $1+1$ is less than $1000$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `amsart` you cannot use `titlesec`.

Just find the definition of `\part` and add

1. `\large`
2. `\let\@secnumfont\relax`

(the latter in order to use boldface for the part number in the title).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\part{%
  \@startsection{part}
  {0}
  {\z@}
  {\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}
  {.5\linespacing}
  {\let\@secnumfont\relax\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}%
}
\show\@seccntformat
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\Roman{part}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{thm}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}

\begin{document}
    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\part{blabla}

\section{blablabla}

\begin{thm}
    The integer $1+1$ is finite.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
    The integer $1+1$ is less than $1000$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]